# Create Bitcoin-Address in PHP

Tags: php, bitcoin

I would like to generate a Bitcoin-address (public/private key) in PHP. I searched a lot, but can not find any working solution.

This for example:
https://github.com/mikegogulski/bitcoin-php

```
addr_from_mpk($mpk, $i)
```

Here for example I dont understand the parameters. The example:

```
$mpk = '675b7041a347223984750fe3ab229df0c9f960e7ec98226b7182a2cb1990e39901feecf5a670f1d788ab29f626e20de424f049d216fc6f4c6ec42506763fa28e';

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    print addr_from_mpk($mpk, $i) . "\n";
}
```

What is happening here? Is $mpk the private key? If I change a single char in $mpk, I get an error.

Can somebody help me out? Is there a working way to generate a Bitcoin-Address in PHP?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin address and public/private key is not the same. Address is basically a representation of a public key. In your code $mpk is a master public key. You give MPK to algorithm and it gives you address back. You can see how it works in that scheme https://en.bitcoin.it/w/images/en/9/9b/PubKeyToAddr.png

I don't see methods to create keypair in repo you provided so you probably have to use something else. You have to create keypair using other tool. I found some PHP code https://github.com/RobKohr/PHP-Bitcoin-Address-Creator and it looks like it created keypair the right way

```
openssl  ecparam -genkey -name secp256k1 | tee data.pem &>/dev/null
openssl ec -text -noout -in data.pem | head -5 | tail -3 | fmt -120 | sed 's/[: ]//g'
```

Comment: It executes a shell command which really should be avoided. I've seen some that use OpenSSL within php itself, avoiding exec() and related.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it using [BitcoinECDSA](https://github.com/BitcoinPHP/BitcoinECDSA.php):

```
$bitcoinECDSA = new BitcoinECDSA();

$nonce = 'addSomeRandomness';
$bitcoinECDSA->generateRandomPrivateKey($nonce);

$wallet_private_key = $bitcoinECDSA->getPrivateKey();
$wallet_pubic_key = $bitcoinECDSA->getPubKey();;
$wallet_address = $bitcoinECDSA->getAddress();
```

Answer (score -1):

Most of the PHP for bitcoin libraries rely on a very much out of date elliptic curve library.

I'd suggest using one of mine, one of which is based on Mike Gogulski. There hasn't been a lot of bitcoin dev happening in PHP besides this :-(
This is `bitwasp/bitcoin-lib-php`

```
<?php
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

use BitWasp\BitcoinLib\BitcoinLib;
$keySet = BitcoinLib::get_new_key_set();
echo $keySet['pubAddr'];
```

This lib is stable enough, but takes some shortcuts, and really expects you know what you're doing.

Then there's `bitwasp/bitcoin-php` - newer, faster, OOP, even comes with an extension to speed it up. But I'm not tagging a composer version until the dust settles :)

```
<?php
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

use BitWasp\Bitcoin\PrivateKeyFactory;

$private = PrivateKeyFactory::create();
echo $private->getAddress()->getAddress();
```

That said, you do **not** need an mpk to make a bitcoin address. An MPK is for a deterministic wallet, and is a serialized [x, y] point. So you will get an error if you pass a point that's not on the curve.

I strongly advise you read more about bitcoin and the underlying principles, as it's clear you are still new to this..